# Ajax push data to array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

It's now about few days that i'm trying to get the data from an php page (array) and to store the array's data in a jquery array. The problem is that when i'm sending the data to the php page like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test2.php?pro=<?php echo $project_name ?>',
    data: {verifie : JSON.stringify(PassArray)},
    cache:false,
    success:function(html) {
         console.log(html);
         $.each( JSON.parse(html), function( key, value ) {
             var value2 = value
             PassArray.push(value2);
         });
         console.log(PassArray);
    },
    error:function(err){
    console.log(err);
    }

});
```

I'm receiving the data the code send me the same array, because i want the php page to send me other articles that contains other id's (different from the id's of the array that i sent in jquery):

```
<?php
$verifie2 = array();
$final = array();
function keyword_sys() {
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

global $verifie2,$final;

$string = $_GET["pro"];

$verifie = json_decode($_POST["verifie"]);

$project = array();
$stopwords = array();

$count = 0;

$string = preg_replace('/[\pP]/u', '', trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/iu', '', mb_strtolower($string))));
$matchWords = array_filter(explode(' ',$string) , function ($item) use ($stopwords) { return !($item == '' || in_array($item, $stopwords) || mb_strlen($item) <= 2 || is_numeric($item));});

foreach ($matchWords as &$value) {
    include("connect.php");

    if($verifie == null || $verifie = ""){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM keyword WHERE keyword = '$value' LIMIT 5";
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM keyword WHERE keyword = '$value' AND project_id NOT IN ( '" . implode( "', '" , (array)$verifie ) . "' ) LIMIT 5";
    }

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    foreach  ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {

        $project_id = $row["project_id"];
        $keyword = $row["keyword"];

        if (!in_array($project_id, $verifie2)) {

            array_push($verifie2, $project_id);

            $compaire = array();

            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM keyword WHERE project_id = '$project_id'";
            $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
            foreach  ($conn->query($sql2) as $row2) {

                $key = $row2["keyword"];
                array_push($compaire, $key);

            }

            $nb_array = count($compaire);
            $nb_array2 = count($project);

            $project2[] = $project_id;
            $project1[] = count(array_diff($compaire,$matchWords));

            reset($compaire); 

        }

    }

    foreach  ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
        $project_id = $row["project_id"];
        if (!in_array($project_id, $project)) {
            array_push($project, $project_id);
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
    }
}

$n = count($project2);

for ($x = 0; $x < $n; $x++) {
    $val = array_keys($project1, min($project1))[0];
    array_push($final, $project2[$val]);
    unset($project1[$val]);
    unset($project2[$val]);
} 

print json_encode($final, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
keyword_sys();
?>
```

Thanks for reading and for your help, I hope it's clear.

Comment: What is the exact problem with the code you have posted? If it is just converting the returned json to the required format, you should post only that code and the json that gets returned from the php script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that i don't know how to save the array from the success: function(html{..} in PassArray and to send it correctly to the php page.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to empty the array before adding new items:

```
success: function(html) {
         console.log(html);
         PassArray = []; // added line
         $.each( JSON.parse(html), function( key, value ) {
             var value2 = value
             PassArray.push(value2);
         });
         console.log(PassArray);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  but : the problem is that i don't know how to save the array from the success: function(html{..} in PassArray and to send it correctly to the php page. So I don't want to empty it again...